# apt-get update stuck

Tags: release-freya, software-installation, pantheon-terminal

Today I tried to install megasync icons from this https://github.com/cybre/megasync-elementary repository but process stuck on this line because my provider is blocking mega.nz site in my country. How can I stop this process? Everytime when I use "apt-get update" I get stuck process on this line.

Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `mega.nz` from the repo list. You can do that using the GUI:
[image]

sorry for the dutch screenshot